# How to Create a PTR Record for AWS Mailserver's Elastic IP Address

Tags: email, dns, postfix, aws, smtp

I configured an SMTP server (Postfix) on an AWS instance. However, as a defense against spam most well-managed emailservers will reject messages ***sent*** from any host whose IP does not resolve back to the same hostname of the sending server.

When I sent a test message from the CLI:

```
mail -s 'TEST Subject' addressOfRecpient@test.com <<< 'Test Message Sent from Postfix Server'
```

It gets rejected by the recipient's mailserver.  ***How do I create a PTR record for the Elastic IP assigned to my AWS mailserver?***

Answer (score 0):

Since Amazon owns the subnet your Elastic IP was assigned from, they need to create the PTR record for you.  You can't set it in your own DNS records *unless of course you control the subnet of Internet-routable IPs you're creating PTR records for*.

Had been a while since I had to do this, but after a bit of Googling I finally found a link in an old (2010) AWS blog post where their users can submit a request for a PTR IP-to-NAME mapping.

### Step 1:

Set the **A** and **AAAA** Records in your DNS to resolve to your mailserver's AWS Elastic IP IPv4 & IPv6 addresses.

**WARNING**: Only the IPv4 address is an "***ELASTIC IP***"- if you destroy the AWS VM and recreate it, although you can reassign the Elastic IPv4 IP to the new instance, this is **NOT** possible with the IPv6 address.  You must submit a new PTR *IP-to-Name* mapping request to AWS every time you recreate a VM with for the IPv6 address.  The IPv4 PTR record will remain correct for the Elastic IP.

### Step 2:

**AFTER** your DNS changes are propagated, you next log into your AWS Console and visit below link where you can request AWS to create the *IP-to-Name* mapping you require** for your IPv4 & IPv6 Elastic IP's:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts?#/rdns-limits

Once they've processed your request, Amazon will send you a confirmation email that the record was created.

After the changes propagate you can check the PTR record using the `host` command.  Below example uses an IP 1.2.3.4 querying Google's DNS of 8.8.8.8:

```
host -t PTR 1.2.3.4 8.8.8.8
```

Which reports:

```
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mail.myMailserver.org.
```

I'd suggest requesting the PTR record from AWS in advance of the mailserver going live so there's no delay related to propagation.